# MapBox Navigation Module doesn't compile on Android

Tags: navigation, mapbox, direction, mapbox-android

Suddenly, I started getting this error while building my project in Android:

Could not GET 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/mapbox/navigator/mapbox-navigation-native/7.0.0/mapbox-navigation-native-7.0.0.aar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Anyone faced a similar problem?

It's as if the Mapbox are using bintray.com to store their binary files there and that server isn't accessible anymore.

Also, I tried to build their navigation examples found on their site and these latter return the same error.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Mapbox Support, they informed me that they changed the methods how they do the authentication. Now we need to follow the following to have access to the Navigation Module of Mapbox:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/beta/navigation/guides/install/

That made it work for me.